# Autohotkey If WinActive

Tags: autohotkey, 3dsmax

Here is the script I am using to use the key 1 to send 1 if active window is 3ds max or else go back in explorer and browser. My code only works if the window is a newly opened unsaved 3ds max file. How do I get it to work with any 3ds max file? I know the ahk_class of max is 3DSMAX.

```
1::
if WinActive("Untitled - Autodesk 3ds Max 2018")
{
    Send, 1
}
Else
{
    Send, {Alt Down}{Right Down}{Right Up}{Alt Up}

}
Return
```

**The official documentation says this**

```
if WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") or WinActive("ahk_class" . ClassName)
```

but neither this works

```
if WinActive("ahk_class 3DSMAX") or WinActive("ahk_class" . ClassName)
```

Nor this works

```
if WinActive("ahk_class 3DSMAX")
```

Nor this works

```
WinActive("ahk_class" . 3DSMAX)
```

---

I cannot use

```
#IfwinActive ahk_class 3DSMAX
```

even though it works because my script is using intercept to use the macro keys on Razer Naga Hex, to send separately from my keyboard keys and it will get very complicated once I start adding all of the software I use.

Here is the full script

```
#HotkeyInterval 20000  ; This is  the default value (milliseconds).
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 2000
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent 

#if (getKeyState("F22", "P"))
F22::return
;=========================================

1::
if WinActive("Untitled - Autodesk 3ds Max 2018")
{
    Send, 1
}
Else
{
    send, {Alt Down}{Right Down}{Right Up}{Alt Up}
}
return

;=========================================
2::
send, {Ctrl Down}z{Ctrl Up}
return
;========================================
3::
send, {Ctrl Down}y{Ctrl Up}
return
;=========================================
4::
send, {Alt Down}{Left Down}{Left Up}{Alt Up}
return
;=========================================
5::
return
;=========================================
6::
return
;==========================================
7::
return
;==========================================
#if
return
```

Comment: I would check that the ahk_class truly is 3DSMAX or that the window is active when you think it is. The sytax `if WinActive("ahk_class 3DSMAX")` is correct. Besides using a window spy utility, you could also check the details above using `WinGetClass, class, A` to get class of active window and then `msgbox, class is %class%`

Comment: Agreed, for max 2018 it should rather be "ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon" or "ahk_exe 3dsmax.exe".

Comment: @Swordslayer omg thank you so much! solved my problem :)